# BI RTF rows breaking across pages

Tags: bi-publisher, jde

I have RTF template that extracts sales invoices. The item details has 3 rows per item and is working fine if the no of lines is printed in one page. If the lines crosses to next page some times the row details gets splited to the next page. What I want is if the value moves to the next page then the entire line (3 rows) should move to the next page. I have unchecked "Allow row to break across pages" but it didn't work. I also tried "Keep with next" in paragraph properties and it didn't work.

Comment: Are you still having this issue and are you using an MS Word table (where you are checking the break across pages)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a table inside a table for this purpose, or better, just put your content in the same cell with an enter between your elements. It's needs to be on a single row if you dont want it to break apart.

[image: xml publisher table]